# Error adding data to mysql with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, mysql, insert, mysql-insert-id

I cannot connect to the database in any way. I installed xampp on my computer and ran Apache and mysql services. But I cannot record anything. I can't query.

I wanted to save the value entered in the textboxes to the mysql database with the help of a button, but I could not succeed. This time, I thought I would at least enter the fixed record into the database, but I couldn't do that either. I wish I could save the value entered in the inputs to the database. I guess it's not connecting to the database.

```
<input type="button" value="Home" class="homebutton" id="btnHome" onClick="Javascript:window.location.href = '127.0.0.1\xampp\htdocs\tester\conn.php';" />
```

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "deneme";
$password = "deneme";
$dbname = "deneme";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO please (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `'127.0.0.1\xampp\htdocs\tester\conn.php'` perhaps you don't know how URL's work? you need `/` not \ ... and also, that URL is **relative** to the current page URL - the `127.0.0.1` is NOT an IP address for this address ... you'll what *at least* `//` at the start of that

Comment: 127.0.0.1//xampp/htdocs/tester/conn.php I didn't try it this way and I got the error that the file could not be found. Actually, I installed xampp on my computer and I run the code I want to run from the same computer. Since I'm working on the same computer, I think I shouldn't need this much code. I'm so confused, please help. I have xampp on my computer and running mysql and apache. I want to save data to a database there with the help of some boxes. I want it to record when I press the button. I tried a lot of codes but now my brain is about to fail.

Comment: You still are looking for a URL that has 127.0.0.1 as part of the PATH (not the domain) ... you need at least `//` at the start of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do should be done using JavaScript function you cannot bind onchange function directly to php script. you have to use either pure javascript function or using javascript library like jquery to make ajax request call to the php script and add the data to mysql database

Check Below code using pure javascript

index.html

```
 <input type="button" value="Home" class="homebutton" id="btnHome" onClick="add_record();" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function add_record(){
     
        var data= document.getElementById("btnHome").value; // get value from input
        xhttp.open("GET", "php_file.php?field="+data, true); // get request url with field parameter  
        xhttp.send(); // make request

    }
 </script>
```

php_file.php

`<?php
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "deneme";
$password = "deneme";
$dbname = "deneme";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$field_data = $_GET['field'];  // get field parameter from request url 


// insert $filed_data into database . You can add as much as fields in request parameter
$sql = "INSERT INTO please (field) VALUES ('$field_data')";



if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>`

Both You html file and php file should be in same folder.
you cannot add xampp folder and htdocs folder in url as htdocs is the
main public folder to access by url and anything above this cannot be accessed via url. please have a look on how to access url on xampp apache server.
Ex: your request url on xampp installed on C: drive should be like this

http://127.0.0.1/my_project/index.html

folder structure should be
C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\
my_project should have both files.

EDIT :

How are you doing it can you please explain

are you able to access  http://127.0.0.1/
try using   http://localhost/  reply what you are getting.

Your URL should be
http://127.0.0.1/tester/conn.php
or
http://localhost/tester/conn.php

Comment: Please  the one who downvoted please add comment  why he feels this so that i can improve for future.

Comment: please upvote my comment  if this helped you.